# How to get binary post data in Django !nicely?

Tags: django, django-views, python

forgive me if this is a bit of a newbie question, I started to learn Django yesterday, and I'm trying not to get into bad habits, i.e. I am trying to do things "the django way" from the start.

I have a view that recieves binary data as a http post field. Now Django of course autoconverts my binary data to a unicode string.

My question is, how do I just get the raw binary data?

A couple of things occurred to me. Let `request` be the request I'm processing.

- Using `request.raw_post_data` would involve parsing the data *again* - when appearantly `request.POST` actually stores raw data and I am actually just trying to get around the on-the-fly conversion (and besides, that is new in the development version).
- Using base64 or so to transfer the data would work, but seems like too much overhead when the data transfer itself is not the problem.
- doing `request.encoding="foo"` before getting that field (and reassigning afterwards) doesn't work either because I still get a unicode string, besides feeling like a bit of a dirty hack. Using `"base64"` here (not as bad as for the transfer encoding) gives me an
  `AssertionError`.

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

EDIT:
To clarify - I am not talking about a classic file upload here, but as binary data stored in a POST field. I'd like to do it that way because the only way I want to interface with that view is via an upload script. Using a normal POST field makes both the client and the server much simpler in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some might say that storing binary data in a standard form field is a bad habit in some way :)

You could use standard library methods of Python to convert your string back to a binary representation.

Take a look at [binascii — Convert between binary and ASCI](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html)

---

Posting before edit:

What about this piece of code (receiving data from a POST)

```
def handleFile(self, request):
    file = request.FILES["file"]
    destination = open('filename.ext', 'wb')
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Works for me.

Comment: Just write in binary "wb" just in case! We don't want Linux<->Windows newline incompatibility to mess up our binary.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for - in my case, the file is actually transmitted as content of a POST field, not as a file upload, because I want to store it in a database anyway. Since the interface to the view I mentioned is an upload script, I thought that using tempfiles of any kind on the server would be unnecessary.

Comment: Well, it's not a standard form field - there is no form, just a `httplib.HTTPConnection`. But yeah, makes sense, what I'm doing is a dirty hack anyway. Thanks a lot!